# Performance issues with the TransitioningContentControl in Windows Phone 7

Tags: performance, windows-phone-7

When using the TransitioningContentControl and a Panorama, I cannot seem to get any good performance when I am navigating from one page to another.

I have been implementing a basic Flip animation, where the current content gets flipped out and the new one is flipped in, but the apps FPS drops to less than 20FPS which means you never get to see the first half of the animation, which is a real pain...

How can I ensure that the animations runs so that the phone can handle the transition?

I dont think its my panorama, its not that full of stuff...

Comment: how much, and what, is in the panorama?  Can you recreate with very sparse content and no background image? Just trying to identify possible causes of perfomance issue.

Comment: there is only 4 panoramaitem controls, and 3 of them are lists with 20 items in each, and the 4th is just some basic controls. There is a background image, but I dont know how to get around that...

Answer (score 1):

Is this on the emulator or on an actual device?  From what i've heard, depending on your hardware, the CPU performance is better on the emulator, but the graphics performance can be much better on an actual device.

Are you transitioning **to** to the panorama or **from** the panorama?  If you're transitioning to it, can you "delay load" the content of the panorama items' lists?

Comment: Im going **from** it, it also seems to be just as bad on the device :(